# ODBC Select Column with Spaces - doesn't like square brackets

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I have a query in Access97 that inserts into an Access97 table from Sql Server 2016 as follows:

```
INSERT INTO [alarm]
SELECT priority FROM [commonservices.alarm] IN '' 
[ODBC;DRIVER=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;
 SERVER=.;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
 DATABASE=CommonServices];
```

This works fine.

My problem is, if I want to select a column that has a space in the name e.g "Alarm Gag", when I wrap with square brackets then I get the error "Circular reference caused by alias 'Alarm Gag' in query definition's SELECT list.

So, if I run:

```
INSERT INTO [alarm]
SELECT [alarm gag] FROM [commonservices.alarm] IN '' 
[ODBC;DRIVER=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;
 SERVER=.;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
 DATABASE=CommonServices];
```

Then I get:

[image]

I have the same problem if I try with [priority]

Any ideas how I can work around this?

Comment: Ah sorry, corrected now

Comment: Try specifying the table: `SELECT [commonservices.alarm].[alarm gag]`. That usually fixes circular reference errors.

Comment: Then I get "Invalid bracketing of name '[commonservices.alarm].[alarm gag]'  -- for: INSERT INTO [alarm]
SELECT [commonservices.alarm].[alarm gag] FROM [commonservices.alarm] IN ''

Comment: alarm.[alarm gag] worked :)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth can you add as answer so I can mark as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circular reference errors are caused by a column alias being the same as the column name.

They can be avoided by specifying the table name for the column causing the circular reference error.

```
INSERT INTO [alarm]
SELECT alarm.[alarm gag] FROM [commonservices.alarm] IN '' 
[ODBC;DRIVER=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;
 SERVER=.;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
 DATABASE=CommonServices];
```